# Corrupted elements for SVN commit

Tags: svn, lotus-domino, subversive, domino-designer-eclipse

I've some corrupted elements in my locale workspace before commit. Everything is right into NSF, but not in locale synch. Expecially a Java script library, in which some methods results duplicated (synch from nsf to on-disk create duplicates).

Which could be the problem?

Comment: There's no question in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

Be careful to have "Use binary DXL for source control operation" flag checked in Designer -> Source Control preferences.

[image]

Infact, it seems that if you don't have it, the export of the element lose some data.